# Windows Forms app slows down after about 12 hours

Tags: c#, .net, winforms, performance

A Programmer in my office has written an incredibly large application in Windows Forms.  Anyways, he keeps having trouble with the application slowing down after about 12 hours. We have confirmed that it is the actual Event Loop that ends up running slowly and not the code after the events fire. For instance, even typing into a textbox will be extremely slow. He has several socket communication threads, which we have confirmed are running at normal speed. The only thing I can think of is that he has several System.Timers.Timer instances throughout the application. Could they be the problem? The program slows down usually after no one has been using it for about 5 or 6 hours.

I know there could be a long list of possible issues. We just need some advice on where to start looking. I have tried all of the obvious.

One other thing to mention. His architecture consists of a base form, which includes a panel with controls that every page has along with 3 timers, and all other forms inherit from this base form. There are probably 15 or so of these forms, all of which are loaded into memory at startup. We did this, because the client was complaining about switching between the forms the first time took a few seconds. Each form has potentially fifty to one hundred instances of a control we wrote for him to use which does all of his back-end work. There is a static timer in this control and one static thread as well--since there is only one instance regardless of how many instances of the control are in memory, I can't imagine that those are the issue. Also the base form's timers are static.

I cannot vouch for the efficiency of his code, but it does run really well at our office, and for 5 to 6 hours on site.

Any ideas?

Edit:

I just talked to the guy on site and he asked. 1st, the event handler for one of the static timers is not static--how that it is possible for a static timer to access an instance method seems weird to me. Second, the timers' AutoReset is set to true.

**Update:**

Ok, I finally got with the guy today to look at some of the code.

He had several static members of his class, i.e. the timers, some buttons, and user controls. Then in the constructor he was using the new operator on each of those static members without a static bool isInit flag.

In other words, the static members were being initialized each time a new form was created but only the last one initialized was being referenced. However, I would imagine that the Form Container was holding references to the old objects so the old objects would never get deleted. Also, wouldn't this be bad aliasing for the containers if the object were to be deleted when the static member's reference was changed? Either way, a bad leak, or a bad alias would cause problems. I am hoping that is the only problem.  I am having him fix all of that and then we will test again.

To add insult to injury, he was calling GC.KeepAlive(the static timer) that had a new reference inside the constructor. So, he had 21 timers running.

Comment: Does he _ever_ unsubscribe from events that are no longer needed?

Comment: @Oded I don't think he has any events that aren't needed for the lifetime of the app.

Comment: post some code, this sounds more like a rant

Comment: @Woot4Moo How is asking for advice a rant? I need an approach to the problem, and the code base is tens of thousands of lines. Also, the man with the code is on a job site waiting for me to advise him. I don't think you need code to offer me ideas about places to start looking.

Comment: I'd start with [CLR Profiler](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff650691.aspx).  If that doesn't help you narrow it down, start putting StopWatches inside methods and log the time to execute.

Comment: My guess would be some memory leak, check for IDisposables

Comment: @jberger. We logged the moment the event handler was entered and the moment it was finished. They were good. The problem is that the event handler takes forever to fire. We didn't use CLR Profiler but we did log the memory usage for 12 hours, and it actually went down over time. Would you say that is an insufficient check for a memory leak?

Comment: @Jonathan actually code would be the best way for us to see the issue, on account of it is clearly a logic failure.

Comment: @Woot4Moo To post enough code for you to see anything useful, it would be thousands of lines. This is simply not an option. I am certain it is a logic failure. It would be sufficient for me to know what kind of logic failure to look for before I waste a week learning code I didn't write. I did design the architecture, so I can certainly explain that.

Comment: @Hinek, if an IDisposable goes out of scope, doesn't the Dispose method get called by the GC?

Comment: Are you performing any special painting?  Is every control "tied" to just one single event handling method?  What are you doing in your timers?

Comment: @jberger, thank you for your interest! If by special painting you mean are we drawing anything ourselves to the screen, no. However, he does have huge Auto-cad generated architecture drawings as the background for each form. Almost every control on the page is the user control we wrote. It has one click event and it is running fine--once it fires. It also receives an event from a static network listening thread and passes it back to the main UI. Anyhow, it would seem odd to me if the images are causing problems, especially if the problem happens after no one has been using the app for hours.

Comment: @jberger, the app runs at about 180000kb and stays, even when it is running slow.

Comment: @jberger, oh and one of the timers updates a label with the time. another runs about 100 lines of code--he also stops the timer at the beginning of the method and restarts it when he is finished. When I looked at the architecture about 2 months ago, I had him take all heavy computing out of his timers and had him put it in background threads. The timers are my number one suspect though, since it slows when there is no user interaction.

Comment: The fact that it runs fine at your office but slows down onsite is the first clue I'd be investigating.

Comment: @Jonathan, objects going out of scope will *eventually* get reclaimed by the GC, but not necessarily right away. What's more, the GC won't call `Dispose` (unless your classes have finalizers that do this). If you want to be on the safe side, you should `Dispose` *all* objects that are `IDisposable` once you no longer need them.

Comment: "In order to prevent resource leaks, you should unsubscribe from events before you dispose of a subscriber object. Until you unsubscribe from an event, the multicast delegate that underlies the event in the publishing object has a reference to the delegate that encapsulates the subscriber's event handler. As long as the publishing object holds that reference, garbage collection will not delete your subscriber object."

Comment: #Charles, ask for their computer specs and compare with yours.  #stakx, consider wrapping temporary IDisposable objects into [using constructs](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/yh598w02.aspx).  @JH, how often is the static network listening thread event firing?

Comment: @jberger, there is a service on a server on the network sending events from PLCs on the network to all subscribed client control machines. This event is firing every time one of those PLCs' bit values are toggled. However, at the moment it is slowing down it isn't firing at all since no PLCs are being used.

Comment: @stakxx No forms or controls are going out of scope to begin with. However, even if I need to do this. Could I just dispose of everything in the Destructor?

Comment: Are you doing any caching? If so, I have seen apps slow down after some time if cache doesn't get cleaned up periodically.

Comment: I rememberded somthing, may or may not be relavent, see edited answer

Comment: @zero7 If the guy doesn't know how to do caching, is it possible for him to do it on accident?

Comment: Does yours ever slow?  You said that their are between 50-100 custom control instances on a single form.  What happens if there is just one custom control on each form?  I'm thinking all of the custom controls are the same control (in a list-like view) which provides some sort of editing to PLC memory..?  It seems like it should be possible to just have one of the custom control (at the top) and a list of the editable items.  When the user clicks on an editable item, the top custom control changes to reflect the selected item.

Comment: @jberger Each control represents a locking control. Each one writes to a different PLC and has different states. Each one has to act as an individual.They aren't in a list either. They are statically positioned on top of the architectural drawings.

Comment: @jberger Mine never slows, but I am running a pretty kick ass machine.

Comment: Try either or both: #1: send the customer some test binaries with just one of the controls on each form. #2: add more controls to your form to see if it slows.  If either confirms my sneaking suspicion of too many controls, then: either A: optimize your code to only create the max number of controls needed and move them around and update, and change their state with scrolling/panning/etc. (PITA and expensive) OR B: ask the customer to upgrade his computer (send him a new one if he doesn't (it'll be cheaper for everyone)).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Are you disposing? Are you holding objects in memory? Are you holding on to some other unmanaged resource.

Leave it running, wait till it gets slow, attach a debugger, step through and see which lines are slow in your problem area.

EDIT:

If it only goes slow on site then, if the product is for a specific client you should construct a reference environment that matches the clients as closely as possible. This would be both useful for the future, and useful now for identifying the differences between your systems which are likely the cause of the problem.

I did have a similar sounding issue where we performed some remoting over sockets on background threads between several services on different machines. Unfortunately I can't remember the exact details (sigh.) As I recall we kept requesting at a set time interval but, the reponse time from the service got slower over time, eventually the response time exceded the set interval. This was fine for the first 1000 or so calls, .Net kept a nice growing stack of the callbacks we were expecting. However, eventually this list reached some internal limit and the message pump froze, including all the painting on client GUIs. This was resolved by ensuring that we would not call until we had had a response. This kind of race condition may or may not be what you are experiencing but I thought it may be worth mentioning.

Comment: thanks for answering! He holds on to all objects in memory. We do not have a memory leak though--That was the first thing I had him check. The difficulty of debugging is that it is the event loop that seems to be running slow. Once the actual delegate is entered, it runs at normal speed. There are at least 6 threads. All are running fine except for the main ui thread.

Comment: Is twelve hours always up at around the same time of day? Can the behaviour be replicated at different locations? Does the configuration of the machine appear relavent?

Comment: I certainly think it could be the machine, but I have checked all of the usual suspects. Power Settings, firewall, disk defragmenter. Any other things I should check?

Comment: hmm that's interesting seeing as how we have a few background threads running socket listeners. However, we don't do any requesting. The client machines register with the service on startup, the service then sends out udp messages for signaling purposes on any event it receives to each registered client. The listeners are just doing an async receive.

Comment: I am going to accept this as the answer because. A.) The problem is initialized objects that he was loosing the reference to but were never getting deleted. B.) Objects weren't being disposed of properly. Thanks.